# How do I assign a Public IP to a Container in PROXMOX

Tags: bridge, proxmox

I initially created vmbr1 and did not assign it an IP. Used it as a bridge for container that had the public IP assigned to it. It did not work. I don't understand what else needs to be done.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address  173.0.0.138
        netmask  255.255.255.248
        gateway  173.0.0.137
        broadcast  173.0.0.143
        network 173.0.0.136
        dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
        dns-search hospemex.com
# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.168.0.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be my solution:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.10.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.10.1
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your eth0 configuration. If you're bridging to eth0, you don't want eth0 to have an IP configuration.

You want

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

for eth0 and nothing else. Also, double check that eth0 is the NIC you want to bridge to and have that pass through to the VM. That is, eth0 is where your WAN link is plugged in. You should also reread the [Proxmox Wiki on networking](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Model).